# Left Join on Associative Table

Tags: sql, mysql, outer-join

I have three tables

Prospect -- holds prospect information

```
id
name
projectID
```

Sample data for Prospect

```
id | name | projectID
1  |  p1  |  1
2  |  p2  |  1
3  |  p3  |  1
4  |  p4  |  2
5  |  p5  |  2
6  |  p6  |  2
```

Conjoint  -- holds conjoint information

```
id
title
projectID
```

Sample data

```
id | title  | projectID
1  | color  |  1
2  | size   |  1
3  | qual   |  1
4  | color  |  2
5  | price  |  2
6  | weight |  2
```

There is an associative table that holds the conjoint values for the prospects:

```
ConjointProspect
id
prospectID
conjointID
value
```

Sample Data

```
id | prospectID | conjointID | value
1  |      1     |      1     |   20
2  |      1     |      2     |   30
3  |      1     |      3     |   50
4  |      2     |      1     |   10
5  |      2     |      3     |   40
```

There are one or more prospects and one or more conjoints in their respective tables.  A prospect may or may not have a value for each conjoint.

I'd like to have an SQL statement that will extract all conjoint values for each prospect of a given project, displaying NULL where there is no value for a value that is not present in the ConjointProspect table for a given conjoint and prospect.

Something along the lines of this for projectID = 1

```
prospectID  | conjoint ID  | value
    1       |      1       |   20
    1       |      2       |   30
    1       |      3       |   50
    2       |      1       |   10
    2       |      2       |   NULL
    2       |      3       |   40
    3       |      1       |   NULL
    3       |      2       |   NULL
    3       |      3       |   NULL
```

I've tried using an inner join on the prospect and conjoint tables and then a left join on the ConjointProspect, but somewhere I'm getting a cartesian products for prospect/conjoint pairs that don't make any sense (to me)

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, c.id, c.title, cp.value
FROM prospect p
INNER JOIN  conjoint c ON p.projectID = c.projectid
LEFT JOIN conjointProspect cp ON cp.prospectID = p.id
WHERE  p.projectID = 2
ORDER BY p.id, c.id
```

```
prospectID  | conjoint ID  | value
    1       |      1       |   20
    1       |      2       |   30
    1       |      3       |   50
    1       |      1       |   20
    1       |      2       |   30
    1       |      3       |   50
    1       |      1       |   20
    1       |      2       |   30
    1       |      3       |   50
    2       |      1       |   10
    2       |      2       |   40
    2       |      1       |   10
    2       |      2       |   40
    2       |      1       |   10
    2       |      2       |   40
    3       |      1       |   NULL
    3       |      2       |   NULL
    3       |      3       |   NULL
```

Guidance is very much appreciated!!

Comment: Your conjoint table sample... first column has all 1's... did you mean for this to be sequential 1-6 instead?

Comment: DRapp -- yes, I did.  Thanks for pointing that out.  I've edited the sample data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then this will work for you...  Prejoin a Cartesian against all prospects and elements within that project via a select as your first FROM table.  Then, left join to the conjoinprospect.  You can obviously change / eliminate certain columns from result, but at least all is there, in the join you want with exact results you are expecting...

```
SELECT 
       PJ.*,
       CJP.Value
    FROM 
       (   SELECT 
                   P.ID ProspectID,
                   P.Name,
                   P.ProjectID,
                   CJ.Title,
                   CJ.ID ConJointID
               FROM 
                   Prospect P,
                   ConJoint CJ
               where 
                       P.ProjectID = 1
                   AND P.ProjectID = CJ.ProjectID
               ORDER BY 
                   1, 4
         ) PJ
         LEFT JOIN conjointProspect cjp 
             ON PJ.ProspectID = cjp.prospectID 
            AND PJ.ConjointID = cjp.conjointid
     ORDER BY 
        PJ.ProspectID,
        PJ.ConJointID
```

Comment: Excellent! Works as advertised.  I wasn't aware that there could be more than one condition in the ON clause.  That being the case, I can also extract the desired records with an inner join on prospect and conjoint and then left join the conjointprospect using the same ON clause used in your solution.  "SELECT  p.id prospectID, p.name ProspectName, c.id conjointID, c.title conjointTitle, cp.value
FROM prospect p
INNER JOIN conjoint c ON p.projectID = c.projectID
LEFT JOIN conjointprospect cp
ON cp.conjointID = c.id AND cp.prospectID = p.id
WHERE p.projectID = 2
ORDER BY p.id
"

Thanks DRapp!!

Answer (score 0):

Your cartesian product is a result of joining by project Id - in your sample data there are 3 prospects with a project id of 1 and 3 conjoints with a project id of 1. Joining based on project id should then result in 9 rows of data, which is what you're getting. It looks like you really need to join via the conjointprospects table as that it what holds the mapping between prospects and conjoint.

What if you try something like:

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, c.id, c.title, cp.value
FROM prospect p
LEFT JOIN conjointProspect cp ON cp.prospectID = p.id
RIGHT JOIN conjoint c ON cp.conjointID = c.id
WHERE  p.projectID = 2
ORDER BY p.id, c.id
```

Not sure if that will work, but it seems like conjointprospects needs to be at the center of your join in order to correctly map prospects to conjoints.

Comment: Thanks Ryan -- I had thought the same thing -- put the ConjointProspect table in the "middle".  I've tried your suggestion but it unfortunately only returns the rows that exist in the ConjointProspect table.  It appears to be the equivalent of 

"SELECT p.id prospectID, p.name, c.id conjointID, c.title,  cp.value
FROM prospect p, conjoint c, conjointprospect cp
WHERE c.id = cp.conjointID AND p.id = cp.prospectID AND p.projectID = 2
ORDER BY p.id, c.id"

thanks for taking the time to respond